# Getting errors in Java when trying to use Stanford Core NLP tools

Tags: java, classpath, stanford-nlp

I am having issues where I'm getting various errors when trying to use the Stanford Core NLP tools. My aim is to have a pipeline running on a server similar to [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer) so that I can make requests as needed from another program and don't have to wait for the models to be reloaded each time (which takes ~20 seconds).

However I've not been able to get the tools to work either when running my own code from Netbeans with the needed jars added to the classpath, or when running code such as the server above and setting the classpath to the jars on the command line.

I've been trying to get this to work for days and really don't know why it's not working.

I've tried doing exactly as the top answer states at [Error in stanford nlp core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528080/error-in-stanford-nlp-core), using exactly the same sample code and adding the same jars to the classpath (except using the jars from a more recent version of the tools). The only difference I can see between mine and theirs is that I'm using Linux and Netbeans rather that Windows and Eclipse, but I don't see why that would make a difference? I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
```

when trying to run this code.

I've also tried setting the models explicitly when trying to run the tools in a servlet on Tomcat, however I then get a ClassNotFoundException for nu.xom.node when trying to make a request to the servlet - however xom.jar is on the classpath.

Thanks for any help, I can give more detail about anything if needed, I tried to give links to the code and error messages but apparently can't put more than two in a post.

Update:

Stacktrace when running code as in second link above:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:558)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:267)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
        at NLP.main(NLP.java:13)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:763)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:294)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:259)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:97)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:77)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:556)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:446)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:758)
        ... 10 more
```

Error message when making request to servlet which loads the models explicitly:

```
Jul 25, 2014 5:04:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CoreNlpServer] in context with path [/CoreNLP-Server] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.xom.Node
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.xmlPrint(StanfordCoreNLP.java:948)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.xmlPrint(StanfordCoreNLP.java:935)
        at CoreNlpServer.doGet(CoreNlpServer.java:44)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What's the entire stacktrace? Also, you'd need to explicitly check the deployed jars' contents to ensure you're deploying what you think you are.

Comment: When I run the code as in the second link I get this stacktrace:

Comment: (Add additional info into the question.)

Comment: When I run the code as in the second link I get [this stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/nfu5Kxn1), and when I make a request to a servlet I get [this](http://pastebin.com/hFZv9GEa). And I'm not sure what you mean by the second part, how would I check and where should it be?

Comment: Sorry I'd add it to the question but I can't put more links in it.

Comment: Have done so now, didn't want to take up loads of space and wasn't sure if it would format correctly.