# NoClassDefFoundError StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, apache-storm, sentiment-analysis

I have this problem when i tired to submit topology in `local mode` !

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NLP.init(NLP.java:16) ~[classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268) ~[na:1.6.0_38]
... 20 common frames omitted
```

i don't know what can i share to help you to fix it ! please tell me .
I'm using `stanford 3.4.1` with `java 1.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Stanford NLP libraries are on classpath.

If you are running your project using Eclipse, this link might help you - [Error in stanford nlp core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528080/error-in-stanford-nlp-core)

Comment: thanks for replying . i'm still confusing in CLASSPATH , i added all jar files i need for stanford but jar files are exist in Desktop and added it from there. Should jar files for stanford exist in specific place ?

Comment: The missing class should be present in stanford-corenlp.jar

Comment: you are right . jar file i submitted doesn't contain StanfordCoreNLP class . what should i need to do now ?

Comment: Find out where stanford-corenlp.jar is present on your machine, and put that on classpath.

Comment: if you mean by adding it in Classpath by adding jar file of stanford-corenlp i'm already added it and add dependency for in pom file but can you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792688/failed-to-execute-goal i skipped the error by maven update in eclipse then mvn package , jar file for project appeared but without class